# Usage : Am yet to read those

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, pronouns

Conversation :

> A- I am reading the Harry potter series.
>
> B- I am yet to read those.

or is it better to use  "I am yet to read them"

or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Ok.. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: It depends on whether you have the intention of reading those in the future or not. "I haven't read those yet" "I am still to read those"

Comment: _Them_ isn't only used for people. That is a crazy thing to say.

Comment: @Vickyace: what gives you that idea? _Them_ is the normal (in fact the only) third person plural non-deictic pronoun, and can refer to anything: people, animals, objects, abstracts.

Comment: @ColinFine Sorry about that. I might have misled him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatical and natural. *Those* puts an emphasis on the books ("those as opposed to any others"), which *them* does not, and leaves it on the speaker ("My status with regard to them is that I haven't yet read them").

**Edit:** thinking about it, it's the "I am yet to" that sounds a bit unnatural to me. Perfectly grammatical, but rather literary. I would say "I've yet to read them", or even more likely "I haven't read them yet".

**Further edit:** It occurred to me that this might be a regional question. Looking on GloWbE, I find that "am/are/is yet to" are recorded nearly three times as often on UK sites (2391) as on US ones (836), and nearly as often on Indian (2030). I am British, but as I say, I find this rather literary; but the figures would suggest that it is less familiar to US readers. I am not surprised to find it more common on Indian sites: Indian English ofen appears rather formal to me.

Comment: ok.. Which is the better usage? I am comfortable with "I am yet to read them" but it kind of sounds wrong.

Comment: No, *those* is stronger than *them.* "Oh, I haven't read those, but I have read *The Cuckoo's Calling.*"

Comment: @AndrewLeach when we use "yet" it sounds better to use "them".. "I haven't yet read them." Right?

Comment: @Colin Are you sure "I've yet to read them" is right? I doesn't sound right. And yes __"I haven't read them yet"__ is a nice way to put it.

Comment: @AniMenon If you know the answer to the question, why bother to ask it? You are asking questions of Englishmen, and then saying we have it wrong.

Comment: @AniMenon: yes I'm sure. It is not something I would say, because "is/are/am yet to" is a rather literary phrase for me, but it's perfectly grammatical and (in a literary context) natural. The choice between "them" and "those" is completely free, as regards grammaticality and naturalness.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It was a doubt I wanted cleared. The above comment of Colin clarifies it.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing between "them" and "those" would depend on the context.  If we were discussing a number of different books I would use "those" because as a deictic pronoun it refers to particular items, separating them from any others under discussion that I might have read.  On the other hand, if the comment about Harry Potter books was not in the context of other books, I would use "them" because there's no need to distinguish them from some other ones.

Comment: So are you saying when we are talking about the same category of books "them" is right otherwise its "those"?

Comment: Not exactly.  What I meant was that when there were no other books to be distinguished from, i.e. we were only talking about Harry Potter, I would use "them".

Comment: Why so? When we are specific it should be "them"?

Comment: Of the two words, "them" and "those", "those" is more particular.  It refers to specific elements of a set whereas "them" doesn't make any distinctions or even imply that any might exist.  It's simply a third person plural pronoun.